# angular 4 - Fetches all assets from server for every route change

Tags: angular

I am working on a angular 4 project scaffolded using cli. For every route change, I could see in the chrome network tab, all assets being requested again. I assumed only certain needed components and api requests would go to server after the first page load.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this the expected behavior.?

[image: Network activity screenshot]

Comment: How are you navigating between routes? Are you using the routerLink directive? The router service (router.navigate method)? If you are using the html href attribute for anchor tags, this will cause your app to reload on route change

Comment: I am using href :) Will try routerLink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is a SPA so it must handle the routing. The href attribute is causing the app to reload. Instead of using the anchor attribute `href` use angular's built in routing directive `routerLink` or the `router.navigate` / `router.navigateByUrl` methods from the router service provider.

routerLink - https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

navigate / navigateByUrl - https://angular.io/api/router/Router

Answer (score 1):

Angular build is done using angular cli and internally it used `webpack` so there is no way that all the files will be reload again!

As angular is a single page application and have its way called `rotuer` to move from one page to another. So if you will not use angular router then of course it will understand that you are loading the application for the first time.

#### loading of application

When you request a page from the url depending upen the router, it will take you to the page.

if you have a router like below, that means what ever url you try to call, it will redirect to hame page.

```
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

So when you call a page using `href` it understand that you are requesting the page for the first time and loads everything.

I would say to start reading routeing.